# I am implementing Django email sender, however , it is giving me an error that some module is not found

Tags: python, django

Following is the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.mail.backends.smpt'

views.py:

```
def register_patient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone= request.POST['phone']
        pic = request.POST['picture']
        print(name)
        patient = Patient(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, photo=pic)
        patient.save()

        subject = "Thank you for registering"
        message = "Welcome the the clinic."
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = [email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
        print("fsfsdf")

    return render(request, "thanks_reg.html",{"name" : name})
```

imports:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
```

I have imported django.core.mail. Perhaps, it reqiures some other module to be imported

Comment: Misspelling.  That is supposed to be `smtp`, not `smpt`

Comment: Edit the question and show us the full error traceback message.

Comment: module is not found means you have to install those packages via running command pip insatll module_name also edit your question and show the full error message which also said jhone